# Download PHP array as a file

Tags: php

I have an array with 3 attributes. I want to create a downloadable link for a file which has the array in a tab-delimited format.

```
ATTR1     ATTR2     ATTR3
23.7      45.89     1.09
....      .....     ....
....      .....     ....
....      .....     ....
```

Comment: What does the array actually look like? e.g. print_r($array); or var_dump($array);

Comment: do you mean you have an array of arrays which in turn have the structure you describe? like array(array('attr1' => 23.7, 'attr2' => 45.89, 'attr3' => 1.09), array('attr1' => 32.4, 'attr2' => 58.9, 'attr3' => 10.9), array('attr1' => 72.3, 'attr2' => 58.49, 'attr3' => 19.0))

Comment: Actually, I want to create a download link for results of $row = mysql_fetch_array($result). $row has 3 attributes.

Comment: Then use fputcsv directly against the $row as you fetch it from the database, rather than building up an array first

Comment: What do I put in href to download this file handle ? <a href="#">Download File</a>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$headings = array('ATTR1','ATTR2','ATTR3');

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp,$headings,"\t");
foreach($array as $row) {
   fputcsv($fp,$row,"\t");
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should output content like ususal and set addition header (before you output any content).

```
<?php
header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment, filename="NAMEOFFILE.tsv"')

// output content in tab delimited format below
?>
```

And then point your link to this script. When user hit it - download window appear (or file will be opened in application, depends on browser settings).

Comment: The best answer is changing the header to the filetype you are trying to provide as a download. The contents are near irrelevant for making the page a file.

Comment: Of course, you can send Content-Type header, but sometimes browser could decide to show this file as plain text instead of downloading. You could force downloading by adding Content-Disposition header. Better way is providing both headers :)